# Getting Started with ELISAs

Tags: elisa

I'm interested in designing an ELISA to detect the presence of Aflatoxin B1, but I'm having a hard time finding information about designing an enzyme and some sort of guidance on how ELISA protocols are designed, and generally where I can get more information. I'm in Grade 9 and am extremely unexperienced to a lot of the terms I'm coming across, but I'm very interested and would be grateful if anyone has a book or a website I can visit to get started or give me some sort of direction.

Thanks,
Joshua